# jQuery AJAX not sending hashtag symbols which causes my request to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have a problem. I'm working with Elixir Phoenix and React.JS. I have a Token that is used to verify the user. This Token also has hashtags in it so when I send a request to verify it, it is being sent without the hash symbols and what comes after them which makes my request to fail. How can I solve this issue? For some reason I don't have that problem when I use fetch with React Native, but here I do. I tried many variations as you can see in the image.
[image]

Comment: It might the sending it. Only that you need to decode them in your server code.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the code as text.

Comment: Hashes are not sent to the server. They were initially implemented as markers for html pages. You can encode that before sending but I would suggest using a different token format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash and anything after it will not be sent by browsers in a request.
You should encode the token so that the hash is escaped.

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/'+encodeURIComponent(accesstoken), {
```

Comment: Thank you, I really struggled with this for some reason. I will approve it in 3 minutes :)